# Hibernate criteria is not working to join three table .

Tags: hibernate

I am using three table and want to return three table as Object[] so that i can retrieve Object[0] as PMSP0200 and Object[1] as PMSPWC02 and Object[2] as PMSJUS01.Below is my query which i want to execute either using Criteria or HQL. Its giving the error as dot node with no left hand side join. This error is coming only when i am joining third table . If i join only two table then it is working fine. Please reply on priority by using either criteria or HQL. I would be thankful of you.

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("PMSP0200DAO_selectPMSP0200AndPMSPWC02ById");
            query.setString("id02", id02);
            query.setString("location", location);
            query.setString("master0co", master0co);
            query.setString("policy0num", policy0num);
            query.setString("symbol", symbol);
            query.setString("module", module);
            query.setCharacter("trans0stat", trans0stat);

            List resultList = query.list();
            if (resultList != null && resultList.size() > 0) {
                Object rowResult = resultList.get(0);
                arrayRowResult = (Object[]) rowResult;
            } else {
                status.setSqlCode(DBAccessStatus.DB_EOF);
            }


HBM

<query name="PMSP0200DAO_selectPMSP0200AndPMSPWC02ById">

select Pmsp0200TO, Pmspwc02TO,Pmsjus01TO 
from com.csc.pt.svc.data.to.Pmsp0200TO Pmsp0200TO ,
com.csc.pt.svc.data.to.Pmspwc02TO Pmspwc02TO,
    com.csc.pt.svc.data.to.Pmsjus01TO Pmsjus01TO where

Pmsp0200TO.id.symbol = :symbol and
Pmsp0200TO.id.policy0num = :policy0num and
Pmsp0200TO.id.module = :module and
Pmsp0200TO.id.master0co = :master0co and
Pmsp0200TO.id.location = :location and
Pmsp0200TO.id.trans0stat = :trans0stat and
Pmsp0200TO.id.id02 = :id02 and

Pmsp0200TO.id.symbol =Pmspwc02TO.id.wc02Symbol and 
Pmsp0200TO.id.policy0num =Pmspwc02TO.id.wc02PolicyNo and 
Pmsp0200TO.id.module= Pmspwc02TO.id.wc02Module and 
Pmsp0200TO.id.master0co = Pmspwc02TO.id.wc02MasterCo and 
Pmsp0200TO.id.location =Pmspwc02TO.id.wc02Location  and
Pmsp0200TO.id.trans0stat=Pmspwc02TO.id.wc02Status  and


Pmsp0200TO.id.symbol =Pmsjus01TO.id.symbol and 
Pmsp0200TO.id.policy0num =Pmsjus01TO.id.policy0num and 
Pmsp0200TO.id.module= Pmsjus01TO.id.module and 
Pmsp0200TO.id.master0co = Pmsjus01TO.id.master0co and 
Pmsp0200TO.id.location =Pmsjus01TO.id.location                  
</query>
```